# divs within table cell behaving badly

Tags: html, css

firstly I have provide a codepen to help resolve this issue.

The issue is with the content within the `divs` going well outside the table cell. 
for instance the content within `div.product-details` is 'book of 30'. I have been trying to center that content within the `div` but its seemingly impossible without adding extra `html` tags around the content.

How can I ensure the content stays within the table cell and the div?

http://codepen.io/pxs/pen/ZORByJ

```
section.prepaid .form-row {
  //there is too much code to put here and it is too hard to format
}
```

Comment: Not sure where to begin.. you have some invalid CSS classnames, like this: `<pre class="brush: php; gutter: false">`

Comment: that crap is generated by woocommerce

Comment: the pre tag screws everything up. if i could stop woocommerce from outputting it, itwould be fine.

Comment: Sorry woocommerce. Its securepay woocomerce plugin that outputs the pre tag and the invalid markup. I have contacted their tech support about this.

Answer (score 0):

the pre tag was not generated by a plugin. It was generated when i copied and pasted the shortcode from the documentation pdf. This process sometimes copies some extra markup along with the shortcode. in this case, it was a pre tag.